# NSManagedObject to save or insert check

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a `UIViewController`, which has **Save** button in `UINavigationBar`.

This `UIViewController` is used for saving a **New User** as well as **Editing a User**.

On, save button I used to always call `- (void)insertObject:(NSManagedObject *)object;` which fails when I am editing a user, as that managed object is already available.

So, I am using the following check. Is this is the correct way for insert or saving editing user?

```
NSManagedObject *managedObject = someObject;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedContext = someContextObject;
NSError *error;
if(m.objectID.isTemporaryID){
//This means its a new object so, first insert
[managedContext insertObject:managedObject];
}

[managedContext save:&error];
```

Answer (score 1):

My pattern for this is to create a property on the view controller for my managed object.  Pretending that your user class is `User`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) User *user;
```

If I am doing an edit the property will be set with an existing user.  If I am doing a create it will be `nil`.  In my save logic I do a check:

```
- (void)didSelectSaveButton:(id)sender {
    if (!self.user) {
        self.user = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User" 
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];
    }

    //  Rest of the logic to map the UI elements to the properties of my user model
    //  objects, referencing self.user

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [managedObjectContext save:&error];

    // error handling
}
```

This way, my logic for populating the information for a user is the same, regardless if it is an "insert" or "update".